# Getting the list of approved items from status column in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query to my dynamodb using paginator.paginate.

Here is my code:

```
for page_1 in paginator.paginate(TableName=chroma_organization_data_table,
        FilterExpression='#s = Approved',
        ProjectionExpression="#s, organizationId",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={'#s': 'status'}
        ):
print page_1
```

However, I get nothing returned back. I know there are several entries that are in the 'approved' states.

This is how my dynamodb returns data if there are no conditions on it (no FilterExpression)(example)

```
[{u'organizationId': {u'S': u'323454354525'}, u'status': {u'S': u'Approved'}}]
```

So clearly there is an entry where status is approved just when I use paginator, it doesn't work.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot embed string literals in filter/condition expressions. You need to set an ExpressionAttributeValues map equal to `{ ":approved": "Approved" }` and then update your filter expression to be `#s = :approved`.